# GDB in Visual Studio Code doesn't show printf() output to stdout

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-code, gdb, vscode-debugger

When debugging a C project in VSCode with GDB, the output to stdout (through printf()) does not appear on the Debug Console. When using `cppvsdebug`, however, it works.

This is my launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
          {
            "name": "Debug",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
              {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": false
              }
            ],
            "windows": {
              "miDebuggerPath": "C:/raylib/mingw/bin/gdb.exe",
            },
            "osx": {
              "MIMode": "lldb"
            },
            "linux": {
              "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
            },
            "preLaunchTask": "build debug"
          },
          {
            "name": "Run",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "windows": {
              "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.exe",
              "miDebuggerPath": "C:/raylib/mingw/bin/gdb.exe"
            },
            "osx": {
              "MIMode": "lldb"
            },
            "linux": {
              "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
            },
            "preLaunchTask": "build release",
          }
        ]
      }
```

This is the command that is executed to run the debug session (according to the terminal window):

```
'c:\Users\...\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-0.27.1\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe' '--stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-2dvbqvix.1cb' '--stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-1m5j1iy0.ufe' '--stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-oqyothgz.h5l' '--pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-hal3wx4b.uld' '--dbgExe=C:/raylib/mingw/bin/gdb.exe' '--interpreter=mi'
```

The Debug Console shows the "splash screen" info of GDB, but doesn't display any of the output from the printf() statements in my code:

```
=thread-group-added,id="i1"
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.1
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-w64-mingw32".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64.
=cmd-param-changed,param="pagination",value="off"
[New Thread 9488.0x54dc]
[New Thread 9488.0x577c]
[New Thread 9488.0xff4]
[New Thread 9488.0x4918]
```

When I run the Exe file with GDB from the commandline (Git Bash), all the output is displayed normally.

Setting `externalConsole` to true doesn't work (it also doesn't open an external console to begin with).

I'm on Windows 10.

Is there any specific setting I need to adjust for this to work?

Comment: Perhaps you should `fflush(stdout)` in the code for the output to be shown. Especially if there is no newline at the end of the `printf` output.

Comment: The minimal example should be `printf("Hello, World!\n");`   Does that work?

Comment: @Weather Vane Calling `fflush()` doesn't work.As I mentioned, it also works perfectly fine when using GDB from the commandline directly. So I am pretty sure that it has something to do with Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @stark No, it doesn't work.

Comment: You can try to reload your gcc compiler. Check the **mingw-w64** version and download the latest version for your vscode.

Comment: Maybe something wrong with:
```avoidWindowsConsoleRedirection

In order to support VS Code's Integrated Terminal with gdb on Windows, the extension adds console redirection commands to the debuggee's arguments to have console input and output show up in the integrated terminal. Setting this option to true will disable it.```

Answer (score 1):

```
fflush(stdout);
```

after your printf statement worked for me.

printf writes to the output stream stdout. stdout waits to be flushed (so it can then be displayed in the terminal). It must be flushed to be displayed, which is normally accomplished via newline characters (\n) since stdout is line-buffered. (gh)

Comment: FYI. The output was displayed in the DEBUG CONSOLE tab, not the TERMINAL tab in my environment (it may depend on the configuration).

Answer (score 0):

Setting  `"externalConsole"` to true solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up somewhat fixing this. In my launch.json I set `filterStdout` to true (I know it's default but lol): https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference#_filterstdout

Setting `filterStdout` to false does the same thing. So I'm sure there's a bug somewhere. I believe the intention is that setting it to true is supposed to get stdout output into the Debug Console tab.

Now when I call my method that calls printf, I just go into the terminal tab and lo and behold my call is in the Terminal tab!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem just now, too, the program output was not shown in the "Debug Console". Restarting Visual Studio Code helped, now the output is visible again.

Answer (score 0):

Question is very old. But write answer - probably will search it self :-).
I had additon issue - out to debug console broke VS code debuger because  `-enable-pretty-printing` is not working for old version of `gdb` - redirect stdout was helpful for this case too.

- first need start addition tty console.
  if you use docker:
  `docker exec -it debug_vsc bash`. Where `debug_vsc` is name of container.
- you should get console device name by command `tty`

```
# tty 
/dev/pts/0
```

- modify `setupCommands` part in the `launch.json` file:

```
"setupCommands": [{
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true,
        },
        {
            "description": "redirect out",
            "text": "tty /dev/pts/0",
            "ignoreFailures": true,
        }],
```

here we told to gdb - "change out of application to other console - `/dev/pts/0`".

In addtion to that possible avoid GDB cash:

```
"pipeTransport": {
            "debuggerPath": "stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 /usr/bin/gdb",
            "pipeProgram": "docker.exe",
            "pipeArgs": ["exec", "-i", "debug_vsc", "sh", "-c"],
            "pipeCwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
},
```

here modified `"debuggerPath": "stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 /usr/bin/gdb",`

Answer (score -1):

It will however output on newline.. so as a workaround, add a '\n' to flush.