# STM32 For Vscode extension printf to console

Tags: c, macos, visual-studio-code, printf, stm32

I am using macOS as my developing OS. I have recently downloaded all the required tools to setup programming environment. I am trying to program STM32WB55 nucleo board. I have created a default makefile project using STM32cubeMX and I am using stm32 vscode extension to build/flash and debug my device.

I am able to build project and flash it without any issue, however, I want to setup printf to print to the vscode console but I have not managed to do it yet. I do not like the fact that everytime I want to print something, I must open a terminal program and connect to the port and then listen to it, it would make much more sense to print it to the vscode console instead.

I have found a few relevant threads such as:
[GDB in Visual Studio Code doesn't show printf() output to stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62665098/gdb-in-visual-studio-code-doesnt-show-printf-output-to-stdout)

However, this solution does not seem to work for me.

My launch.json :

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "showDevDebugOutput": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "executable": "./build/wb55_test.elf",
            "name": "Debug STM32",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "cortex-debug",
            "servertype": "openocd",
            "preLaunchTask": "Build STM",
            "device": "stlink",
            "configFiles": [
                "openocd.cfg"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to add  `"console": "internalConsole",` or  `"externalConsole": false,` both commands are not recognised:

```
Property console is not allowed
```

or

```
Property externalConsole is not allowed
```

Is this a well known issue? Are there any other methods to try?

Comment: The STM32 board is a completely separate computer, without any kind of knowledge of your console. You have to connect the STM32 board to your system, usually with a serial port (and nowdays using a USB-to-serial converter) and then setup the serial port in the STM32 system to be used as the "console".

Comment: The stm32 board is connected to my computer via USB cable. If I understand properly, the USB cable connects to the integrated st-link of the nucleo board. I am able to do ```uint8_t tx_buffer[5] = "hello";
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,tx_buffer,sizeof(tx_buffer),10);``` and the message "hello" will appear on the terminal program. I just want to setup printf so it can send to vscode console. Could you clarify what you mean by saying setup serial port in the STM32 system to be used as a console?

Answer (score 1):

The output of your Nucleo STM32 port is sent to a virtual serial port on your Mac. In order to view it, you have several options:

- Use a terminal program separate from Visual Studio Code. I very much like [Serial](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/serial/id877615577?mt=12). But you might not be willing to spend 40 USD.
- Open a terminal in Visual Studio Code and run `screen`, a command line terminal program. The full command line is something like `screen /dev/cu.usbxxxxxx`. To quit it, type CTRL-A and CTRL-.
- Use the PlatformIO extension. PlatformIO is a powerful tool supporting many platforms including STM32 with STM32 HAL. At the core it's a build system. So it will replace your Makefile setup. But it also has a Visual Studio Code extension with many goodies. It includes a serial monitor that displays the Nucleo output within Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Is there really no other way? As I mentioned, I am able to print the data to the external terminal as well as a terminal in visual studio, but that does not seem like the most convenient way. I just want to simply printf to the IDE console. I remember previously I have used ITM to dispaly data directly on the IDE console and that worked fine for the particular board, however, I think not all boards have ITM module so it is not reliable method that you can use for all boards.

Comment: If you develop a program that will be run locally, the program execution, input and output are tightly coupled and naturally appear in the console. For MCUs running independently on a separate board, that's not the case. You need a separate tool or a special integration into your IDE. That also applies to ITM. It appear in your IDE because the IDE implemented it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Also, I have used to work on crossworks studio environment and we programmed various STM32 microcontrollers using J-links. In there, we could use printf and the messages would show right up in the terminal. Is that because of the crossworks or J link?

Comment: There are two parts: One is enabling `printf`. That's doable in your case as well and you can direct it either to the UART, which is routed via USB to your computer. Or it can be routed to ITM/SWV and via USB to your computer. This works both with the ST-Link on your Nucleo board as well as a J-Link. The second part is receiving the output and displaying, which needs support from the IDE or a terminal program. In case of ITM/SWV, it requires a debugging connection and thus needs the support of the debugger. I guess Crossworks uses the debugger approach.

Comment: Thanks for further help. I haev enabled the printf to send to uart. Now the printf behaves exactly as would UART_Transmit. For my processor (STM32WB55) ITM is not possible I think. I am now looking into how to route it to SWV maybe thats possible? The project is created in such a way that I can use either STM32cubeIDE or vscode with the stm32 extension. I havent been able to setup printf to print to console on either of these yet. Do you know if its possible to do that on either of these IDE's?

Comment: STM32cubeIDE has a view for SWV. I'm not an expert but my understand is it's coupled to ITM and I also believe it should be supported by STM32WB55. As far as I know it doesn't have a terminal for UART/serial port. Visual Studio Code doesn't have an SWV viewer that I'm aware of. SWV/ITM also depends on proper wiring of the SWO pin, which is missing in Nucleo-32 boards and available on Nucleo-64 and Nucleo-144 boards